Leave-one-*in* cross validation
I'm trying to argue that my model is very robust.
Given are $N$-many x-y pairs as samples.
Iterating over all samples, for each sample a model is trained using only this single sample.
This model is then used to predict all other samples.
For each prediction, the error is recorded (producing $N-1$ error values).
In total, this creates $N \cdot (N-1)$ errors.
All these errors are then aggregated by RMSE.
Since the result is close to the RMSE of using all data to train my model, I call the model robust.
For lack of a better word, I've described this as leave-one-in cross validation.
Is this a known idea?

I realize this is an unusual situation.
For clarification, an example.
Assume there are 5 samples numbered 1 to 5.
The model is trained with sample 1. The error of the model on samples 2 to 5 is calculated.
Then a new model is trained with sample 2, and its error on samples 1, 3, 4 and 5 is calculated.
Same procedure for the other 3 samples, each gets its own model.
Then, all errors are squared, averaged and sqrted, so there is an RMSE.
This RMSE is only a little worse than a LOO CV RMSE or a fully trained model (little difference).

you may be interested in "One-shot learning" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-shot_learning_(computer_vision), though this describes a learning task rather than a predictive error estimation strategy.

"Since the result is close to the RMSE of using all data to train my model..." In what way? Most reasonable models tend to have better RMSEs as the training sample size increases. But you seem to be training each model on a sample of size 1. None of these models (neither individually, nor on average) are likely to have RMSEs close to the RMSEs of training models on samples of size N.

I would assume the exact opposite, that this will lead to a very unstable model. What happens if you hold out a validation set and evaluate on that? Alternatively, what does the variance of RMSE look like under bootstrapping?

@civilstat Exactly. The validation RMSE of my model, trained with just a single sample, is similar to the LOOCV RMSE. This is unusual, which is why I say the model is robust.

@RandySavage I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but the validation set for each model is the entire remainder ($N-1$) of the samples.

@mafu a validation set in this case would be a subset of the data that is never used in the training procedure, but held out to evaluate the performance of the fitted model

@RandySavage I believe the expected RMSE in that case is equal to the one of the mentioned procedure, perhaps with a little more luck involved.

If I understand you correctly, you have similar values for (1) "leave-one-in" CV RMSE, (2) LOOCV RMSE, and (3) plain old RMSE found by training the model on all N datapoints and assessing it on the same N training datapoints. If so, your model doesn't seem to be learning anything as you acquire more data! That doesn't sound like a good idea.

I'm having trouble imagining how this could happen. Perhaps your model is "take the sample mean of Y" and all N of the Y-values are nearly identical -- but my conclusion from that wouldn't be "my model is good," but rather "my population has extremely low variation." Or perhaps you are using a Bayesian model with an extremely strong prior, so that your posterior doesn't change much whether you add 1 or N datapoints -- but I wouldn't call that "my model is robust," so much as "my model ignores the data."

@civilstat I think the explanation is that my model captures the essential X-Y relationship whereas other models do not, so I suppose they can only fit well by overfitting.

@mafu Can you say anything more specific about your model & situation? Again it's hard for me to imagine a concrete situation like the one you're describing abstractly.

@civilstat I'm not sure how that helps, but let me think of something... Imagine Y ~ X^2 + epsilon, and all conventional models use some linear relationship while my model has the correct quadratic relationship, so any single pair is enough to train it to a high degree.

@mafu So there's just a single parameter to be estimated? For instance in terms of this example there's no intercept, just a single slope for the X^2 term? (Otherwise, how can you fit a model from only one observation?)

@civilstat No, the model is less complex (lower dimension) than the data generator. But yes, the model extracts most of the relevant information from a single sample and the error in the information is not too large.
